# How to return an array of CGPoints using Objective C

Tags: objective-c, swift

I have a function in my project called **doWorkOnSampleBuffer** that returns a value of CGPoint.

```
- (CGPoint)doWorkOnSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer inRects:(NSArray<NSValue *> *)rects {

    CGPoint mypoint[2];

    mypoint[0] = CGPointMake(-1, -1);
    mypoint[1] = CGPointMake(5, 5);

    return mypoint[1]
}
```

This function is called inside another swift file as follow:

```
var myPoint = wrapper?.doWork(on: sampleBuffer, inRects: boundsArray)
```

Now, I would like to make the **doWorkOnSampleBuffer** function return the CGPoint array "**mypoint**", instead of just one CGPoint value.

So, how can I adapt my code to do that?

Comment: Using `NSArray<NSValue *> *` is one way. You know `NSValue` has an initializer taking `CGPoint`.

Comment: @OOPer, I tried:

- (NSArray<NSValue *> *)doWorkOnSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer inRects:(NSArray<NSValue *> *)rects {
    
    CGPoint mypoint[2];
    
    NSValue *pointArray = mypoint;
    
    mypoint[0] = CGPointMake(-1, -1);
    mypoint[1] = CGPointMake(5, 5);
    
    return pointArray;
}

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved!

The answer is:

```
- (NSArray<NSValue *> *)doWorkOnSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer inRects:(NSArray<NSValue *> *)rects {

    CGPoint mypoint[2];

    mypoint[0] = CGPointMake(-1, -1);
    mypoint[1] = CGPointMake(5, 5);

    NSArray *myCGPointArray = @[[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:mypoint[0]],[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:mypoint[1]]];

    return myCGPointArray;
}
```

Now, if you call this function like:

```
var myPoint = wrapper?.doWork(on: sampleBuffer, inRects: boundsArray)
```

So you can access values as follows:

```
myPoint![0].cgPointValue.x
myPoint![0].cgPointValue.y
myPoint![1].cgPointValue.x
myPoint![1].cgPointValue.y
```

Comment: Overcomplicating. Just: `return @[[NSValue valueWithCGPoint: CGPointMake(-1, -1)], @[[NSValue valueWithCGPoint: CGPointMake(5, 5)]]`